# Why does the following code get triggered only after I set a breakpoint elsewhere, and then resume?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, game-center, gamekit

I have created a real-time multiplayer game using game kit. Creating the match etc proceeds normally on both devices. Then the if block :`if (!self.matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0)`never gets triggered, unless I place a break point in the update method of `SKScene`. While the game is running I place a break point. And once the debugger breaks, I "continue" (^ + CMD + Y). Immediately the code in the if block gets triggered.

```
 -(void)match:(GKMatch *)match player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state
    { 
        switch (state)
        {
            case GKPlayerStateConnected:
                // Handle a new player connection.
                break;
            case GKPlayerStateDisconnected:
                // A player just disconnected.
                break;
        }

        //TODO We have to keep track of whether a match has started or not.
        if (!self.matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0)
        {
            self.matchStarted = YES;
            self.gameState = _proposingBestHostState;
        }        
    }
```

My `SKScene update:` method is effectively a NOP, since it calls a method on self.gameState which is nil until it is set in the if block.

self.matchStarted is a property with the following attributes:

```
@property (nonatomic)bool matchStarted;
```

Comment: The breakpoint creates a delay and changes the timing. Obviously the message is sent before the receiver is ready for it.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, as this method is called by game kit.

Comment: When this happens to me, I add like 100 NSLogs everywhere, log every ivar, every object, every failed match, etc. There is probably no magic answer - its going to take a lot of detective work. I still think its a timing issue, but the system is complex so no magic place to put one probe.

Comment: I have plenty of logs - Its as if the method does not get called by game center until I continue from the break point.

Comment: Then I suggest you post in the internal apple forums, you might get an apple engineer to help. If that doesn't result in an answer, burn one of your two DTS incidents on this issue.